# Django set lang is not working in IExplorer but working in Chrome

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have this form in my page to change the language of website on the fly:

```
 <form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="image" name="language" value="ar" src="{{ img_static_url }}maroc.png"/>
      <input type="image" name="language" value="fr" src="{{ img_static_url }}france.png"/>
  </form>
```

But this work fine only in Chrome, but not in Internet Explorer and Firefox

What is the problem?

I submit the form using jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by :

```
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="snw-fb btn btn-xs btn-default" type="image" name="language" value="ar"
                           src="{{ img_static_url }}maroc.png" height="23"/>
</form>
<form action="{% url 'set_language' %}" method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <input class="snw-fb btn btn-xs btn-default" type="image" name="language" value="fr"
                           src="{{ img_static_url }}france.png" height="23"/>
 </form>
```